# What was the first anime to have characters blasting off?

Tags: tropes

Instantly, *Pokemon*'s [team rocket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUqY1.jpg) comes to mind when I think of characters blasting off after losing a battle, just to become a twinkle in the sky<sup>[tvtropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ATwinkleInTheSky)</sup>.

However, it has become rather popular in lots of shows!

[image: Luffy blasting Alvida Off]
[image: If you're a man, fly to the heavens and become a star!]

I'd like to know what was the first anime that featured characters blasting off and if possible, whether or not the first instance of this was in Anime?

Comment: [A Twinkle in The Sky](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ATwinkleInTheSky) . . . you just need to search for anime/manga release date . .

Comment: TV Tropes is neither complete nor accurate. As far as accuracy, they're somewhere between a random forum and some blowhard's blog, not as good as Wikipedia but better than your crazy uncle who believes Elvis is an alien princess.

Answer (score -2):

From what I understand this trope actually dates all the way back to Greek mythology. Apparently, Hercules did this to someone.